# Configuring SAML2: Bypassing 'InResponseTo' Validation While Retaining Default Settings in OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a Java back end application running behind Nginx and spring security for SSO .My back end app lacks a mechanism to remember cookie sessions because of which SSO request could be initiated by one java instance and assertion might reach to other instance . The existing default implementation requires the validation of the `InResponseTo` attribute if it's present. The default implementation is based on http session which keep tracks of session via cookies.The purpose of keeping cookie is to remember id attribute and later match with `InResponseTo` to protect from replay attack. `InResponseTo` is optional atribute in SAML2.0 spec.  I want to know if there's a way to disable the `InResponseTo` validation while still utilizing the default validation provided by `OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider`. Notably, SAML2 considers the 'InResponseTo' attribute optional. What is the best method to maintain default validation but bypass `InResponseTo` through back end configuration settings?

My application basic configuration looks like below .

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  SamlSuccessHandler successHandler;

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    ).saml2Login(saml2->{
      saml2.loginProcessingUrl("/saml/SSO")
          .successHandler(successHandler);
    }).build();
  }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          sap-account400:
            entity-id: my_entity_id
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: https://my-service.com
              singlesignon.sign-request: true
            assertingparty:
              metadata-uri: https://okta.com/1234
            decryption:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: classpath:private_key_encryption.pem
                  certificate-location: classpath:certificate_encryption.crt
            signing:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: classpath:private_key.pem
                  certificate-location: classpath:certificate.crt
            acs:
              location: http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO
```

Comment: Hi, Sumeet. Please indicate the version of Spring Security that you are using.

Comment: I am using spring security 3.1.5 and spring-security-saml2-service-provider 6.1.4

Comment: @jzheaux Looking for your input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the `InResponseTo` validation, you will need to customize `OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider`. By default, it validates the status code, the `InResponseTo` attribute, the `Destination` attribute, and the `Issuer` attribute.

The simplest way to do this is to remove the `InResponseTo` validation result like so:

```java
@Component
final class ResponseValidator implements Converter<Response, Saml2ResponseValidatorResult> {
    private final Converter<ResponseToken, Saml2ResponseValidatorResult> delegate = OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseValidator();

    @Override
    public Saml2ResponseValidatorResult convert(ResponseToken response) {
        Saml2ResponseValidatorResult result = this.delegate.convert(response);
        Collection<Saml2Error> errors = result.getErrors().stream()
            .filter((error) -> !error.getErrorCode().equals(INVALID_IN_RESPONSE_TO))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return Saml2ResponseValidatorResult.failure(errors);
    }
}

...

@Bean
AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(ResponseValidator validator) {
    OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider =
        new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setResponseValidator(validator);
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

However, I'd recommend that you first try and configure your IdP to not include information that you do not intend to validate.

#### Suggested Alternative

Instead of disabling validation, consider storing the requests in some other shared storage (e.g. a cache) on the backend. You can [customize `Saml2AuthenticationRequestsRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/authentication-requests.html#servlet-saml2login-store-authn-request) with relative ease to this end. To be fully SAML 2.0 compliant, a form of caching [is already needed](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf) (see line 602).

Comment: Thank you for answer . My understanding is having InResponseTo helps in protecting replay attack . If saml assertion is https , how assertions will be intercepted unless mitm happens. If you could highlight vulnerabilities system faces if we do not do   InResponseTo validation ?

Comment: The above code will not solve the InResponseTo to ignore from error list because subject confirmation again tries to validate and there is no specific to filter from createAssertionValidator .